# UpdatePanel - Any ideas on how to avoid a flicker in UI? - ASP.NET/Jquery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have rather a complex UI. However, for the purpose of this question, let's say that there is a HTML table that renders UILayout1 by default (say default mode). There is a button that a user can use to toggle between the default mode and a preview mode (UILayout2)

When in preview mode, there are some columns in the table that are invisible and there are reordering of rows. I am using JS (jquery) on load to check the mode and change it accordingly.

The table and the toggle button are in UpdatePanels.

Functionally, everything works as expected. However, when a user toggles between default and preview mode or vice versa, there is this short time interval in which the the table renders in default and then JS runs to make changes.

This results in degraded UI experience. Are there any creative ways to avoid this "flicker"?

Answer (score 1):

you can use DIVs or don't use update panel in your UI generation use any concept else

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely to be that your code is running on load. I'm assuming that you're doing this using the standard jQuery method of running code on load, and not using the window's onload event. In any case, even using jQuerys `$(document).ready(...)` will be too slow if you have a lot of other javascript files to load, as the .ready event isn't fired on the document until all javascript includes have loaded.

You should be able to work around the issue by including your code that modifies the table just after the html for the table in your page and not running it on load i.e. make sure you don't wrap it in `$(document).ready(...);`

For this approach to work, you will need to have all javascript required by the code which is modifying the table included earlier in the page.

If you have other non-essential javascript files included, you should try to include them later in the page.

I'm not 100% sure how being inside an update panel will affect it - you will need to make sure that your code is being re-triggered when the updatepanel updates, but I believe this should all happen automatically.

Comment: UpdatePanels do tend to add a lot of bloat to the page, and are not particularly fast. It's best to avoid using them if you can.

Comment: @Bennor - The sequence of events is 1) the static html loads 2) the jquery runs that updates html based on mode. So, the user sees 1 and 2. I want the user to see only 2.

Comment: If you put code to hide your static html directly after the static html in the page (and not inside a document ready handler) then it will not be rendered. You can then set it up with your other code, and then show it when it's all set up.

If it's taking a while, you can display a loading image instead while the table is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your UI is controlled by CSS? You might be able to get rid of the flickering by adding something like this at the start of your JavaScript or in the <head> of your HTML:

```
if (previewMode) {
    document.documentElement.className = 'preview';
}
```

Then if you modify your CSS rules that apply to your preview mode to reflect the HTML element having the class="preview" to something like:

```
.preview table .defaultMode {
    display:none;
}
```

hopefully your table should render correctly first time and will not need to be re-drawn.